# RabbitMQ MochiWeb on AWS behind Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

I have an AWS setup with an Elastic Load Balancer that talks to a RabbitMQ cluster of two nodes.  There is a plugin called RabbitHub that runs on MochiWeb as a REST interface to RabbitMQ.  My problem is that I get a lot of 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT errors, with or without the load balancer.  I'm forwarding HTTPS to HTTP on 15670 through the load balancer, but even when I go directly to the server through a VPN, I'll get a 504.

It appears that most GET requests work (like the base URL), but I have a significant issue with POSTs.  Sometimes it works...sometimes it doesn't.  I had about 4 good hours today, then went back to a nasty 2 hours.  I'm really at the end of my knowledge here.  What could be causing this?

AWS docs say to increase the keep-alive on the web server.  Is that possible on MochiWeb?

Thanks --
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Well, forget I said anything.  The problem was that a MochiWeb error occurred, which closed the connection immediately.  As a result, the load balancer reports the 504.  If this helps anybody, I checked the SASL logs to see that there was an actual Erlang error.  From there, I could see what the issue was and address it.